# How to add placeholder in select2

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-select2

Here is my php jquery code to generate dropdown dynamically.

It is working fine. But I have to add placeHolder in this dropdown.

So I have added below code but it is not working.

May I know where should I have add this code or something wrong with my code?

```
$('#calc_shipping_state').one('select2:open', function(e) {
                        $('input.select2-search__field').prop('placeholder', 'enter username or city');
                    });
```

Regards,
Alex

```
<?php
    /** 
     * Added state filter for shipping calculater
     */ 
        if ( 'yes' === get_option( 'wc_csz_new_state_field' ) && in_array( WC()->countries->get_base_country(), get_option( 'wc_csz_countries_codes' ) ) ) {
            $country_states = [];
            include( WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/cities-shipping-zones-for-woocommerce/i18n/cities/' . WC()->countries->get_base_country() . '.php' );
            woocommerce_form_field( 'calc_shipping_new_state', [
                'type'  => 'select',
                'options'   => [ '' => '' ] + apply_filters( 'csz_states', $country_states ),
                'class'     => [ 'form-row-wide', 'address-field' ]
            ] );
            ?>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery( function( $ ) {
                    var country = '<?php echo WC()->countries->get_base_country(); ?>';
                    $( document ).ready( function() { new_state_visibility() } );
                    
                    
                    function new_state_visibility() {
                        if ( $( '#calc_shipping_country option:selected' ).val() == country || $( '#calc_shipping_country' ).val() == country ) {
                            $( '#calc_shipping_new_state_field' ).show();
                        } else {
                            $( '#calc_shipping_new_state_field' ).hide();
                        }
                    };
                    
                    $( '#calc_shipping_state' ).on( 'select2:open', function() {
                        $('.select2-search__field').attr('placeholder', 'your placeholder');
                        });
                        if ( $( '#calc_shipping_country option:selected' ).val() == country || $( '#calc_shipping_country' ).val() == country ) {
                            $( '#calc_shipping_state' ).data( 'select2' ).dropdown.$search.val( $( '#calc_shipping_new_state option:selected' ).text() + ' - ' );
                            $( '#calc_shipping_state' ).data( 'select2' ).dropdown.$search.trigger( 'input' );
                            $( '#calc_shipping_state' ).trigger( 'query', { term } );
                        }
                    } );
                    $( '#calc_shipping_state' ).on( 'select2:select', function() {
                        $( '#calc_shipping_new_state option' ).filter( function() { return $( this ).text() == $( '#calc_shipping_state option:selected' ).text().split( ' - ' )[0]; } ).prop( 'selected', true );
                    } );

                    $('#calc_shipping_state').one('select2:open', function(e) {
                        $('input.select2-search__field').prop('placeholder', 'enter username or city');
                    });
    
                } );
                </script>
            <?php
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: You can easily add third party 'select2' scripts to do it.

Comment: The [documentation](https://select2.org/placeholders) didn't help?

Comment: @Tuhin why would third party code be better the placeholder option that Select2 offers? Also comments like "You can easily add" is rarely useful without any kind of link or guide.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure, but I think it was with `data-placeholder` attribute, so something like this
`data-placeholder="Placeholder"`
You can read the documentation about placeholder's [here](https://select2.org/placeholders)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer.

```
woocommerce_form_field( 'calc_shipping_new_state', [
            'type'  => 'select',
            'options'   => [ '' => '' ] + apply_filters( 'csz_states', $country_states ),
            'class'     => [ 'form-row-wide', 'address-field' ]
            'placeholder' => 'State / County',
        ] );
```